# Why is my while loop not repeating as many times as my input says?

Tags: c#, while-loop

My application should get user input as well as a number of repetitions.

After it's verified as positive data, it should display results in a list box.

Results should be phrase # of reps entered.

I know I need to use a while loop but where am I going wrong. Below is what I have so far:

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Delcare variables 
    int Numberofreps;
    int Count = 1;
    string Phrase = txtPhrase.Text;

    //Get the inputs 
    if (int.TryParse(txtNumberofreps.Text, out Numberofreps))
    {
        if (txtPhrase.Text == Phrase)
        {
            lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtPhrase.Text);
        }

        //Check to make sure its a positive value
        while(Count >= 1)
        {
            //Display the number of reps
            lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtPhrase.Text);    
        }           
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not a Positive Value");
    }
```

Comment: Please use a better headline! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in infinite loop since you are not changing the value of `Count` inside.
I would probably change the code to this:

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Delcare variables 
    int Numberofreps;

    //Get the inputs 
    if (int.TryParse(txtNumberofreps.Text, out Numberofreps) && Numberofreps > 0)
    // Note I've added a check that the Numberofreps is a positive integer.
    {
        while(Numberofreps > 0)
        {
            //Display the number of reps
            lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtPhrase.Text);
            Numberofreps--; // Note this line.
        }           
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not a Positive Integer");
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the addition of  (Numberofreps--;) affect the code? Also if I was trying to display the loop count, does that require a do-while or can that be added? Pardon my lack of formatting I'm new and still getting acquainted with the formatting.

Comment: `Numberofreps--;` is a short way of writing `Numberofreps = Numberofreps - 1`. Without changing the value of the loop counter, your loop is infinite. If you want to display the loop count then perhaps Dmitry's answer is better - since it will count from 0 up instead of from `Numberofreps` down.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `for` loop instead of `while`:

```
   private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     int Numberofreps;

     if (!int.TryParse(txtNumberofreps.Text, out Numberofreps)) 
       MessageBox.Show("Not a integer Value");
     else if (Numberofreps <= 0)
       MessageBox.Show("Not a Positive Value");
     else {
       for (int i = 0; i < Numberofreps; ++i)
         lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtPhrase.Text);
     }   
   }
```

If you insist on `while` loop:

```
      int i = 0;

      while (i < Numberofreps) {
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtPhrase.Text);

        i += 1;
      }
```